# How to use velocity to create pdf files?

Tags: java, pdf, velocity

In our application, we have velocity code which generates csv and html reports.
Now we want to add pdf support to it.

So i tried exploring way. But found that we can not generate pdf from velocity. 
so it will be something like first create docx and then from docx to pdf.

I am ok with this way also.

I already have .vm file which is something like:

```
#if ($file.getRecords().size() != 0)
```

bla bla bla....

My java code replaces $file with

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("file", fileCatalog);
```

where filecatalog is clonnable class and has mmethod getrecords ...etc etc.

this setup is perfectly working for csv and html output generation.
but for docx generation, its saying docx is corrupt and cannot be opened.

any idea whats wrong in it?

I wanted pdf as final output. since its not possible directly, so chose making docx first but docx is also giving problems....
request you to please guide....

TIA!

Comment: How on earth should we answer your question (if it is a question at all) given no information? Snippets of your templates, enough code to outline the problem, exact error messages etc. C'mon, this is the first thing you should know as a programmer!

Comment: Docx just like PDF is a binary file format while Velocity is good for text file formats. As you are prepared for a small detour (docx was meant as such a detour after all), why not use XSL FO (XML is a textual format) and use some existing fo-to-pdf converter?